# Pandas DataFrame "info" method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I combine multiple csv files to produce a dataframe. I use `.info()` method for a quick summary of my dataframe and notice an interesting fact about `Int64Index`. This line shows the dataframe contains 20,551,697 (> 20 million) observations, however, the `0 to 1,924,562` confuse me.

Why a dataframe with 20 million entries only has index from `0 to 1,924,562`?

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 20551697 entries, 0 to 1924562
Data columns (total 15 columns):
 #   Column                   Non-Null Count     Dtype  
---  ------                   --------------     -----  
 0   tripduration             20551697 non-null  int64  
 1   starttime                20551697 non-null  object 
 2   stoptime                 20551697 non-null  object 
 3   start station id         20551517 non-null  float64
 4   start station name       20551517 non-null  object 
 5   start station latitude   20551697 non-null  float64
 6   start station longitude  20551697 non-null  float64
 7   end station id           20551517 non-null  float64
 8   end station name         20551517 non-null  object 
 9   end station latitude     20551697 non-null  float64
 10  end station longitude    20551697 non-null  float64
 11  bikeid                   20551697 non-null  int64  
 12  usertype                 20551697 non-null  object 
 13  birth year               20551697 non-null  int64  
 14  gender                   20551697 non-null  int64  
dtypes: float64(6), int64(4), object(5)
memory usage: 2.4+ GB
```

Comment: Maybe duplicates in index, how working rempove them by `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` and then `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: Or check duplicates in index with `df.index.duplicated().sum(), len(df.index.unique())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not default `RangeIndex`, I think reason are duplicates in index values.

You can check it by [`Index.has_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.has_duplicates.html):

```
print (df.index.has_duplicates)
```

For remove duplicates use:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: TQ @jezrael, I forgot to set `ignore_index=True` when combine multiple CSV files with `pd.concat()` method. Found out lots of duplicated index.